# Task related to well-order and topology 2

Tags: set-theory

I have exam in 3 days.And this task was in the prep task list for exam.I have no idea from which perspective I can solve it... But maybe I think this problem can be solved using ordinals.

Let A be a Well-order and B ⊂ A.It's known that for any x,y ∈ B if x < y, than exists z ∉ B, such as x < z < y...and for any x ∈ B, y ∉ B, if y < x, than exists z ∉ B,such as y < z < x. Proof that any element in B is limit element.

Comment: Do not just repost your question if it gets closed: [Task related to well-order and topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128020/task-related-to-well-order-and-topology) Improve the original question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in B$

Assume $x$ has a predecessor $y$. If $y \in B$, then there must be $z\notin B$ with $y<z<x$. This cannot be, since $x$ is the successor of $y$. Likewise, if $y \notin B$, there must be $z\notin B$ such that $y<z<x$. Again, this cannot be.

Therefore, $x$ is a limit element